# Calculus of single variable problem,: To find a function of the cost of material depending on the length of the base side.

Tags: calculus, functions

I need help solving this math problem:

A rectangular storage container with an open top is to have a volume of 10m3. The length of its base is twice the width. Material for the base costs $10, material for the sides cost 6. Find a function of the cost of material depending on the length of the base side.

I tried solving it
[image: What I tried]

and additional notes
[image: Notes]
. You'll see, why I didn't try to type it all in.
I found some similar problems on this site and in other places, however the solutions offered don't seem to be applicable to this specific question.

The solution (as presented by the teacher) should be: $C(b)=20b^2+\dfrac{180}{b}$
I (seem to) manage to calculate the first part, however I get $\dfrac{b}{10}$ for the second part (instead of $\dfrac{180}{b}$).

Can anyone please help point me to my mistake.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have put in some effort to solve the problem yourself.  What have you tried (other than looking for a solution online?)  Where are you stuck?  Put your response in the **body** of the question, **not** in a comment.  The question is likely to be closed by the moderators if you don't add more context.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You are likely to get more positive feedback if you provide some personal efforts, especially on elementary questions.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 0):

Let $w$ and $2w$ be the length and breadth respectively and $h$ be the height.

Then the area of base will be $(2w).(w)= 2w^2$. So the cost (in $\$ $) of the material for the base is $10.(2w^2)$. Two of the sides have the area $w.h$ and the other two have $2w.h$; so the cost of the material for the sides is $6[2(2w.h)+2(w.h)]$.

So the total cost is therefore; $$C=10.(2w^2) + 6[2(2w.h)+2(w.h)]=20w^2 + 36wh $$

To express $C$ as a function of $w$ alone we need to eliminate $h$ and that can be done by using given volume.

$$w.2w.h=10$$

Which gives $$h=\frac{5}{w^2}$$

Substitute this in the expression of $C$ and we can easily get $$C(w)= 20w^2 + \frac{180}{w}$$ where $w$ is positive.

Comment: I think my this (above) explanation is enough and correct.

Comment: That's the solution I came up with originally and found in the forum as well. However two things seem out of place:
1. In the problem it's stated, that the function has to be dependent on the length, which is double the width. Your solution seems to be dependent on the width (or am I mistaken)?
2. In the way the problem is written, the cost is for the total base (or side respectively) NOT per square meter. Shouldn't I therefore have to DIVIDE the cost by the surface?

Comment: Which two things?  And where did you find its solution?

Comment: The solution was given by the teacher.
Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter. I added the explanation now.

Comment: This question is also given in book: calculus- early transcendentals by James Stewart. And answer is also right.

Comment: I found the book online and also the question. https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Maths/Calculus/Calculus%20-%20J.%20Stewart.pdf
There are two variants:
1) On page 15: it uses the WIDTH of the container and it states the cost of the material per square meter.
2) On page 328: it asks for the CHEAPEST possibility.

I'm really at my wit's end.

Comment: I redid my calculations. Would you mind taking a look at them and pointing out my mistake?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Jf1.jpg

Comment: Seems to be correct (if there is not given per square meters).

Comment: ***One Suggestion:-***  You should write the question properly, mentioning your attempt. Also try to make a least use of pictures. Learn Mathjx / TeX codes. It would be helpful to you for getting answers fast & correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll confront the teach today. Thanks for all your help and your tips. I'll make sure to write the question more properly next time. I actually wanted to add pictures, however I'm not able to yet. Next time then.